# How to Set Custom Delimiter in PIG

Tags: mapreduce, apache-pig, cloudera, hue

What is the correct syntax to set a custom TextInputFormat delimiter in Pig? I've tried several variations on the following but its treating it as string values instead of Carriage Return Line Feed.

```
set textinputformat.record.delimiter '\r\n';
```

Pig Version is 0.12.0-cdh5.9.0 and Hadoop Version is 2.6.0-cdh5.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ideal but a workaround:

Create a properties file like `myprops.properties` which contains the following line: `textinputformat.record.delimiter=\r\n`

Then run your script like: `pig -P ~/myprops.properties -f path/to/pigscript.pig`

It looks like this is a known issue as mentioned in the fourth paragraph of the fourth comment of: [PIG_4572](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-4572)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax

```
SET textinputformat.record.delimiter '<delimiter>';
```

This works for me

Comment: This doesn't work with control characters because it's treats the value as a string.

Comment: @shawn did you find any solution for this?